# Two requests are generated on single hit in spring

Tags: java, spring

In spring application, when application get started it hits two times database i.e. it take two requests. or when refresh the application it takes again two requests.
plz suggest

```
private DBDao dbDao;

public ModelAndView getRecords(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, FormBean formbean) {

    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    dbDao.getRecords(formbean.getId(), formbean.getNamne())

    //Doing some calculations

    return modelviewObj;

}
```

Comment: Please show us your code snippet which is called twice.

Comment: I have edited the code , it is just a controller method which get called on hitting on url

Comment: Did you debug your code? Does controller gets called twice or some other code?

Comment: Ok I think we need more especially some code were this method is called.

Comment: <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  this is in web.xml

<%response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/getRecords.htm"); %>    
this is in index,xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorryyy, Got the solution, I just submit the form two times. So I handle it and now it works fine